# summary table , R

Tags: r, summary, rscript

I imported an xlsx file into R, the table has many columns, some of them contain numbers and others characters.
when I try to do the summary for the columns that contain characters I get this

```
> Length     Class      Mode  
>       287 character character
```

whereas let's say that my column is this :

```
yes
no
no
yes
```

I'd like to get this :

```
yes:2
no: 2
```

I tried to save the table as a dataframe, but it didn't work, and I also tried to save it as a table but I get "table cannot be coerced" .

any ideas ? thank you :)

Comment: see `?table`. For more help, please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: If you want this outcome you need to set your character column as a factor. Check `summary(iris)` and look at the Species column

Comment: Yes exactly, my table is very similar to the iris (but much bigger : 150 columns with 7 of them that contain numbers , the others are answers such as yes/no and male/female , and 380 row)  , and I want to be able to get the same results , but I don't know how

Comment: How do you import the xlsx file ? There's probably an option to get factor columns instead of character columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the character columns to *factors* if you want such an output of `summary`.

Consider a dataframe with a character column:

```
iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- as.character(iris2$Species)
```

Then you get this unwanted output:

```
> summary(iris2)
  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width    Petal.Length   Petal.Width    Species         
 Min.   :4.30   Min.   :2.00   Min.   :1.00   Min.   :0.1   Length:150        
 1st Qu.:5.10   1st Qu.:2.80   1st Qu.:1.60   1st Qu.:0.3   Class :character  
 Median :5.80   Median :3.00   Median :4.35   Median :1.3   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :5.84   Mean   :3.06   Mean   :3.76   Mean   :1.2                     
 3rd Qu.:6.40   3rd Qu.:3.30   3rd Qu.:5.10   3rd Qu.:1.8                     
 Max.   :7.90   Max.   :4.40   Max.   :6.90   Max.   :2.5
```

To convert all character columns to factors, the `map_if` function of the `purrr` package is convenient:

```
library(purrr)
iris3 <- as.data.frame(map_if(iris2, is.character, as.factor))
```

Then:

```
> summary(iris3)
  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width    Petal.Length   Petal.Width        Species  
 Min.   :4.30   Min.   :2.00   Min.   :1.00   Min.   :0.1   setosa    :50  
 1st Qu.:5.10   1st Qu.:2.80   1st Qu.:1.60   1st Qu.:0.3   versicolor:50  
 Median :5.80   Median :3.00   Median :4.35   Median :1.3   virginica :50  
 Mean   :5.84   Mean   :3.06   Mean   :3.76   Mean   :1.2                  
 3rd Qu.:6.40   3rd Qu.:3.30   3rd Qu.:5.10   3rd Qu.:1.8                  
 Max.   :7.90   Max.   :4.40   Max.   :6.90   Max.   :2.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I just tried it, and I got this :                                        > summary(medata3[,4])
Yes 
  1                                                                                                                                  even tho the column treated gender (male/female)